# GRASS 7.4: r.cross unexpectedly produces category zero

Tags: grass

I have a problem with the output of `r.cross`. I hope you can follow my description without MWE:

I have 3 rasters I want to cross with the following characteristics:

```
GRASS 7.4.0 (Bengue):~ > r.stats soil_t,lcov,watermask -N
 100%
4 8 0
4 8 1
4 9 0
[...]
```

I would expect `r.cross` to create a raster with a category for each line shown above. However, I get the following:

```
GRASS 7.4.0 (Bengue):~ > r.cross input=soil_t,lcov,watermask output=svc    
GRASS 7.4.0 (Bengue):~ > r.category svc
0   
1   category 4; category 8; category 1
2   category 4; category 9; category 0
[...]
```

Why is the first line just zero when one would rather expect something like: `1   category 4; category 8; category 0`?

EDIT: Just noticed that under GRASS version 6.4 it runs as expected:

```
GRASS 6.4.6 (Bengue):~ > r.category svc
0   
1   category 4; category 8; category 0
2   category 4; category 8; category 1
3   category 4; category 9; category 0
```

So, something must be wrong with the 7.4 version of `r.cross`?!

Thanks for your help!

---

System infos:

- GRASS version 7.4.0
- Ubuntu MATE 16.04 (xenial)

Answer (score 0):

just in case somebody comes across this post: It was also asked in the mailing list shortly after this post by somebody else: https://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/grass-user/2018-February/077934.html. As it seems, it is a bug and not yet fixed in the latest release version of GRASS.